# How can I add html in a div repeatedly, but keep pre-existing html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Using Javascript of jQuery I want to swap a string of text for an html tag, over and over, without losing the previous html.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9j26P/2/)

```
<p>This is <i id="text">text</i> and more text</p>
```

This is *text* and more text

```
function rep() {
    var t = $('p').text().replace('text', '<b>html</b>'); 
    $('p').html(t);
}
```

Ideally it would look like:

```
<p>This is <i id="text"><b>html</b></i> and more <b>html</b></p>
```

This is ***html*** and more **html**

I DONT want to change the pre-existing html.  `<i id="text">` should remain in the html, no matter how many times I run the function.  `.html().replace(..` wouldn't work because it will grab the `id="text"`.  Thanks.

Comment: Use `.html()` instead of `.text()` and you'll get all the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sry if I wasn't clear, but I don't want to change the pre-existing html.  So if I use .html() than I'll change the `id='text'` tag, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Oh, that makes things more complicated.

Comment: This question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if this code fits with your needs (I reuse `input` multiple times for convenience) :

```
function rep(input) {
    input = RegExp.escape(input); // http://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/1636522
    input = new RegExp(input + '(?![^<]*?>)');
    input = $('p').html().replace(input, '<b>html</b>');
    $('p').html(input);
}
```

A little help about `(?![^<]*?>)` (roughly : "some text not followed by `>`") :

```
(?!...)   not followed by
[^<]*     any char except "<", zero or more times
?>        until next ">"
```

More on regular expressions : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml.

Comment: Sorry @Squirrl, I've copied your code without thinking. Fixed : `.text() -> .html()`.

Comment: Yes u genius it did http://jsfiddle.net/9j26P/16/ !  Any idea how I can replace `text` with a variable?

Comment: Awesome! Thank u.  It's still getting caught up on parenthesis. Any way u can explain `(?![^<]*?>)'` so that I may be able to tweek it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the old value using `.html()`, not `.text()`, since the latter leaves out all the HTML markup. You can do it in a single call, using a function to calculate the replacement from the old value:

```
function rep() {
    $('p').html(function(i, oldhtml) {
        return oldhtml.replace(/(<[^>]*)?text/g, function($0, $1) {
            return $1 ? $0 : '<b>html</b>';
        });
    });
}
```

Notice that you have to use a regular expression with the `g` modifier to perform multiple replacements in a string. Negative lookbehind would be the normal way to exclude `id="text"`, but this is not available. I used the workaround from [Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent)

Comment: This replaces all the text in one swoop including the `<i id="text">` which I want to retain.  I don't want to change the pre-existing html.

Comment: @wared Yeah, just realized that. I'll merge in the workaround from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent

Comment: Can I suggest this regex : `/(<[^>]*?)?text/g`? `"<text>text text</text>text" -> "<text>azerty azerty</text>azerty"`

Comment: Since `<text>` isn't a valid HTML tag, that seems like overkill.

Comment: Looking good.  THank u, but I want to run it repetitively.  @Barmer Ur function is replacing all the text in one call.  I tried removing the `g` but that didn't do it.

Comment: @Barmar I know `<text>` isn't a valid tag :D It's just an example. The idea is to deal with various situations like `<textarea`, `class="text`, and so on...

Comment: @Squirrl I can't think of a way to do just one. The problem is that the lookbehind workaround matches `id="text"`, and just avoids replacing it. So if you do it without `g`, it won't make any change past that part of the HTML, because it keeps matching it each time.

Comment: @Barmar Well, if it's more clear for you, try with this string : `"<textarea>text text</textarea>text"`. I think it's a valid one ;)

Comment: To do this right, you need to process the text nodes by themselves. You can get ideas from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452340/iterating-through-each-text-element-in-a-page. I'm not going to try to write it now.