# Add class only to numbers in HTML page except on links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried this script inside Joomla to add a class to every number so that I can format them with CSS:

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    $(function() {
      $('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,strong,i,em,b,span,sup,sub').each(function() {
        var el = $(this),
            html = el.html();
        html = html.replace(/(\d)/gi, "<span class='number'>$1</span>");
        el.html(html);
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

It work fine but I've got a problem with links where there are numbers such as:

```
www.miosito.it/index.php&articleid=2
```

In this case it make this:

```
www.miosito.it/index.php&articleid=<span class="number">2</span>
```

So the link is broken. How could I edit the script to fix it?

Comment: One somewhat safer strategy would be to run your regex only over text nodes, not over the raw html, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452340/iterating-through-each-text-element-in-a-page